# What is the differences between methods in Java Queue interface ?

Tags: java, data-structures

Checking out Queue interface in Java [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html)

I got confused by methods definitions :

> element() Retrieves, but does not remove, the head of this queue.

is like

> peek() Retrieves, but does not remove, the head of this queue, or
>   returns null if this queue is empty.

I can see that peek returns null if the queue is empty but both actually are defined as

> Throws: NoSuchElementException - if this queue is empty

Same applies to `remove()` and `peek()`;

Is there any goal behind this or it is just a design pitfall ?

Comment: I guess you meant _Same applies to `remove()` and **`poll()`**_

Comment: The answer is in the docs - [`element`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html#element--): "*Retrieves, but does not remove, the head of this queue. **This method differs from peek only in that it throws an exception if this queue is empty**.*
" `peek` **doesn't** throw an exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's clarify things with a table that should answer your question:

```
+---------+---------------------------+------------------------+
| method  |          action           | throws when not found? |
+---------+---------------------------+------------------------+
| peek    | Retrieves, doesn't remove | NO                     |
| remove  | Retrieves, removes        | YES                    |
| element | Retrieves, doesn't remove | YES                    |                 
+---------+---------------------------+------------------------+
```

There are methods that returns `null` when no element is found, others throws an exception.

The are methods that retrieve and don't remove, others retrieve and remove.

Comment: Good answer, but the more detailed explanation is in Javadoc for Queue interface itself. See the link: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html

Answer (score 0):

The explanation is in java API for interface Queue: [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html). In short element() thows exception if the queue is empty and peek() returns a special value to indicate that the Queue is empty